# Jquery Content slider

Tags: jquery, html, slider

this is the image link for reference.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/TfoD0.png

Hi all i need a content slider which able to autoheight according to the content in each 
div content, 
i have came across alot of the slider but none fit to my criteria,
which is :

1. Auto height for each content.
2. the left and right arrow , should be align to middle when the height changed.
3. thumbnails at below.
4. content inside should be flexible enough to put html5 video / youtube embedded video , and other div content.

i have found some of the slider like 
http://webbies.dk/assets/files/SudoSlider/package/demos/callbacks%204%20%7Bthumbnails%7D.html

it does fit the criteria, but the thumbnails carousel , doesnt have a left and right arrow.
and the left and right arrow on the slider, doesn't allign to center according to each resized content.

any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Like this? 
http://webbies.dk/assets/files/SudoSlider/package/demos/thumbnails%20with%20rich%20content.html

I made SudoSlider, so just ask if you have any questions.

You can look at this demo if you want a method to get full control of your thumbnails. 
http://webbies.dk/assets/files/SudoSlider/package/demos/customLinks.html